# How do I resolve the deployment error "Permission ModifyAllData depends on permission(s): ManageNetworks"

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, migration

How do I resolve the deployment error "Permission ModifyAllData depends on permission(s): ManageNetworks" or "Permission AuthorApex depends on permission(s): ManageNetworks"?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this, you need to edit the affected profiles to give them the "Create and Setup Communities" and "Manage Communities" permissions.

**Explanation**: "ManageNetworks" is the API name for the permissions that allow a user to create and manage Salesforce Communities. This permission is normally auto-enabled when you give other powerful permissions like "Modify All Data", but when managing and deploying profiles in version control it might be missing.

Comment: what does this mean, specifically?

Comment: @OK999 I added some explanation

Answer (score -1):

"Create and Setup Communities" results in:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageNetworks</name>
</userPermissions>
```

"Manage Communities" results in:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>GovernNetworks</name>
</userPermissions>
```